# Django/Javascript: How to pass variable to template filter in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, django

I am currently passing a template variable in `views.py`:

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if scrape.get_countries().count() == 0 or (timezone.now()-scrape.get_global().last_updated).total_seconds()/3600 > 24:
        scrape.fetch_api_data()
        scrape.fetch_time_data2()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_dates': scrape.get_dates()})
```

where all_dates is a dictionary.

In a javascript function in my `home.html`, I want to be able to access values from the dictionary using a key variable called **code**.

```
<script>
 function create_graph(country, code, dates) {
    var date = "{{ all_dates|get_item:code|get_item:'05/05/2020'|get_item:'confirmed'}}";
    window.alert(date);
</script>
```

FYI, get_item is just a simple template filter in another file

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    if key:
        return dictionary.get(key)
```

However, when running the server, I get this error message:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /
Failed lookup for key [code] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'global': <Country: Global>, 'countries': <QuerySet [<Country: Global>, <Country: ALA Aland Islands>, <Country: Afghanistan>, <Country: Albania>, <Country: Algeria>, <Country: American Samoa>, <Country: Andorra>, <Country: Angola>, <Country: Anguilla>, <Country: Antarctica>, <Country: Antigua and Barbuda>, <Country: Argentina>, <Country: Armenia>, <Country: Aruba>, <Country: Australia>, <Country: Austria>, <Country: Azerbaijan>, <Country: Bahamas>, <Country: Bahrain>, <Country: Bangladesh>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>, 'all_dates': {'..': {}, 'AX': {}, 'AF': {'05/04/2020': {'confirmed': 2894, 'recovered': 397, 'deaths': 90}, '05/03/2020': {'confirmed': 2704, 'recovered': 345, 'deaths': 85}, '05/02/2020': {'confirmed': 2469, 'recovered': 331, 'deaths': 72}, '05/01/2020': {'confirmed': 2335, 'recovered': 310, 'deaths': 68}, '04/09/2020': {'confirmed': 484, 'recovered': 32, 'deaths': 15}, '04/08/2020': {'confirmed': 444, 'recovered': 29, 'deaths': 14}, '04/07/2020': {'confirmed': 423, 'recovered': 18, 'deaths': 14}, '04/06/2020': {'confirmed': 367, 'recovered': 18, 'deaths': 11}, '04/05/2020': {'confirmed': 349, 'recovered': 15, 'deaths': 7}, '04/04/2020': {'confirmed': 299, 'recovered': 10, 'deaths': 7}, '04/30/2020': {'confirmed': 2171, 'recovered': 260, 'deaths': 64}, '04/03/2020': {'confirmed': 281, 'recovered': 10, 'deaths': 6}, '04/29/2020': {'confirmed': 1939, 'recovered': 252, 'deaths': 60}, '04/28/2020': {'confirmed': 1828, 'recovered': 228, 'deaths': 58}, '04/27/2020': {'confirmed': 1703, 'recovered': 220, 'deaths': 57}, '04/26/2020': {'confirmed': 1531, 'recovered': 207, 'deaths': 50}, '04/25/2020': {'confirmed': 1463, 'recovered': 188, 'deaths': 47}, '04/24/2020': {'confirmed': 1351, 'recovered': 188, 'deaths': 43}, '04/23/2020': {'confirmed': 1279, 'recovered': 179, 'deaths': 42}, '04/22/2020': {'confirmed': 1176, 'recovered': 166, 'deaths': 40}, '04/21/2020': {'confirmed': 1092, 'recovered': 150, 'deaths': 36}, '04/20/2020': {'confirmed': 1026, 'recovered': 135, 'deaths': 36}, '04/02/2020': {'confirmed': 273, 'recovered': 10, 'deaths': 6}, '04/19/2020': {'confirmed': 996, 'recovered': 131, 'deaths': 33}, '04/18/2020': {'confirmed': 933, 'recovered': 112, 'deaths': 30}, '04/17/2020': {'confirmed': 906, 'recovered': 99, 'deaths': 30}, '04/16/2020': {'confirmed': 840, 'recovered': 54, 'deaths': 30}, '04/15/2020':
```

How am I supposed to pass in a javascript variable into a django template filter? I tried enclosing **code** in double brackets, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because you are passing code variable in double quotes "" and JS will take that as code instead of its value.

To solve this try `+'code'+` in your JS function line and let me know if it worked

Comment: Sorry, do you mean     var date = "{{all_dates|get_item:+'code'+|get_item:'05/05/2020'|get_item:'confirmed'}}";? or     var date = "{{ all_dates|get_item:'code'|get_item:'05/05/2020'|get_item:'confirmed'}}";?

Comment: are you sure that code contains a valid value in that function? Did you try ```+'...+``` on your template filter? It might be that your template filter is also not compiling due to double quotes.
Hard code a print statement in your filter and put a valid key instead of code just to check if your filter is working

Comment: I have hardcoding the variable code to a key I know exists, and it works, so I don't think thats the problem. I get this error:TemplateSyntaxError at /
get_item requires 2 arguments, 1 provided. And if I don't include the plus symbols, I get AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: In fact, if I set code='US' (a valid key) and I run: ```window.alert(code + "\n{{ all_dates|get_item:'code'|get_item:'05/05/2020'|get_item:'confirmed'}}");```, then the template filter receives ```"code"``` as the key, not ```"US"```

Comment: You must include the + symbol otherwise it will not recognize it as a python template tag

Comment: your definition of **get_item(dictionary,key)** has two parameter while in JS function youre only passing the key.

Comment: I thought that with template filter, the variable before | is passed in as reference. So how do I pass in 2 variables using the + symbol method? Can u provide an example?

Comment: Try something like this:


```var a = {% all_dates|get_item:code|get_item:'05/05/2020'|get_item:'confirmed' %};

```

Comment: This isn't javascript code right? That also doesn't work in html. I get an error asking if I loaded the tag: ```TemplateSyntaxError at / Invalid block tag```

Comment: You are right. This is not java-script but template tags are really an easy way to mix javascript and python code  so I suggest to use these. other wise ```+'code'+``` and ```+'get_items..'+```  should have worked in my opinion but template tags will get your job done